# Calculate Percentage Values

Tags: rapidminer

My Rapidminer process results are published as follows

```
Row No. Count
1   9.0
2   11.0
3   32.0
```

If I want to calculate:
    (9/32)*100 and 
    (11/32)*100
from this result set, how would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is not quite straight forward, as RapidMiner normally treats Examples (rows) as independent of each other.

What you can do is to extract the value needed as a *macro* and use it in the *Generate Attributes* Operator.
See the attached sample process for a solution to your particular problem. Just copy and paste the XML below to your process window in RapidMiner.

Also feel free to ask further, or re-post, questions in the [RapidMiner community forum](http://community.rapidminer.com).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="7.6.001">
<context>
<input/>
<output/>
<macros/>
</context>
<operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="7.6.001" expanded="true" name="Process">
<process expanded="true">
  <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="7.6.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Generate Data by User Specification" width="90" x="112" y="85">
    <list key="attribute_values">
      <parameter key="Count" value="9"/>
    </list>
    <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="7.6.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Generate Data by User Specification (2)" width="90" x="112" y="187">
    <list key="attribute_values">
      <parameter key="Count" value="11"/>
    </list>
    <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="7.6.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Generate Data by User Specification (3)" width="90" x="112" y="340">
    <list key="attribute_values">
      <parameter key="Count" value="32"/>
    </list>
    <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="append" compatibility="7.6.001" expanded="true" height="124" name="Append" width="90" x="380" y="187"/>
  <operator activated="true" class="extract_macro" compatibility="7.6.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Extract Macro" width="90" x="581" y="187">
    <parameter key="macro" value="divisor"/>
    <parameter key="macro_type" value="data_value"/>
    <parameter key="attribute_name" value="Count"/>
    <parameter key="example_index" value="3"/>
    <list key="additional_macros"/>
    <description align="center" color="green" colored="true" width="126">Extracting the third value as a macro. It can be the called using the %{macro_name} syntax</description>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="generate_attributes" compatibility="7.6.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Generate Attributes" width="90" x="782" y="187">
    <list key="function_descriptions">
      <parameter key="Percentage" value="5"/>
    </list>
    <description align="center" color="green" colored="true" width="126">Creating a new Attribute (column) with the desired calculation&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Check the final paragraph of the help text for the &amp;quot;Generate Attribute&amp;quot; Operator for a description of how to work with macros</description>
  </operator>
  <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 1"/>
  <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (2)" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 2"/>
  <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (3)" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 3"/>
  <connect from_op="Append" from_port="merged set" to_op="Extract Macro" to_port="example set"/>
  <connect from_op="Extract Macro" from_port="example set" to_op="Generate Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
  <connect from_op="Generate Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 1"/>
  <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
  <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
  <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
  <description align="center" color="yellow" colored="false" height="581" resized="true" width="444" x="56" y="18">Generating sample data to fit the original problem</description>
</process>
</operator>
</process>
```